# Javascript Pass parameter to function inside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign a click handler to a JQuery object, defined in a variable :

```
some.object.array[8].action = function(data){console.log(data);}
anotherobject = {..}
```

now inside some loop, I need to assign this function to the click handler:
and want to pass the whole 'anotherobject' object

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    $('<div/>').click(some.object.array[i].action);
}
```

But how can I pass the parameter?
If I encapsulate it inside some anonymous function, I'm losing my scope...:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    $('<div/>').click(function() {
        some.object.array[i].action(anotherobject)
    });
}
```

because `i` has changed...

How are we supposed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just too many ways to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $('<div/>').click(function() {
            some.object.array[i].action(anotherobject);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Or

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    $('<div/>').data("i", i).click(function() {
            var i = $(this).data("i");
            some.object.array[i].action(anotherobject);
        });
    });
}
```

Or

```
function getClickHandler(callback, parameter) {
    return function() { callback(parameter); };
};
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    $('<div/>').click(getClickHandler(some.object.array[i].action, anotherobject));
}
```

Comment: implementation was a bit complicated, but after all, it works! Thanks, Any idea how you call this way of doing (method1)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
  $('<div/>').click(
    (
      return function(callback){
        callback(anotherobject)
      }
    )(some.object.array[i].action)
  );
}
```

Comment: callback is also out of scope once the anonymous function is executed

Comment: This will not work. When this loop ends, `i` will be outside the bounds of the array and `some.object.array[i]` will return `undefined`. Plus since you are attaching handlers inside a `for` loop, they will ALL use this `undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks, now it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `action` function to maintain the div as `this` and still accept the jQuery event object, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this example:

```
function action(another, event){
    console.log(this, arguments);
}

$(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        var anotherObject = "another"+i;
        var div = $('<div>'+i+'</div>');
        // force 'this' to be 'div.get(0)'
        // and 'arg0' to be 'anotherObject'
        div.click(action.bind(div.get(0),anotherObject));
        $("body").append(div);
    }
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwe5b9cx/ You'll need to open the console to see the output, which should look like this:
[image]